# (Automatic) animation of paths/vectors with XAML/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to implement an play/pause animation in WPF that requires nice transitioning between paths to achive a material-design look.

The animation might look like this:

[image: example desired animation]

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to modify paths in a StoryBoard (neither in Visual Studio Blend nor via XAML) - is there a way to automatically blend between two paths similar to how android handles it ([AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html))? Or is there a way to manually blend between those, specifying the change in values?

The paths are as follows:

```
M12,10L20,10 20,38 12,38z M28,10L36,10 36,38 28,38z              #Pause
M16,24L38,24 27.3,30.8 16,38z M16,10L27.3,17.2 38,24 16,24z      #Play
```

Comment: As stated, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Please provide a good [mcve] showing clearly what you've tried already, and a more detailed explanation of what specific difficulty you ran into, and what exactly the difference is between your best attempt and what you want. It seems to me that you could animate the opacity and rotation of each complete shape to accomplish something similar to your graphic above (I can't say for sure, because the interval in your animation is too short for me to see clearly precisely how the image is changing).

Answer (score 8):

Normally I would definitely agree with @PeterDuniho on the broadness. Except I've been there. So here's a quick `Storyboard` concept example that accomplishes your goal and gives you an insight into animation of `LineSegment.Point` nicely contained.

The key is you need a segment point for every part of the animation not unlike how you would do morph effects with SVG as example. So if one of the shapes in the animation has for example 4 points, and another has 3 points. Well then you still need 4 points on your `Path` the entire time and you just give the *illusion* of the morphing by hiding the existing points within each shape.

So the example below is a simple one but should be enough to get the creative juices going and could be built on and added into something like a `ToggleButton` template with consideration between IsChecked=True/False for an example. If you need more than that, well come back with more specifics or think of folks like me who make a living with this sort of thing. :)

Anyway, throw this grid anywhere and mouse over it to invoke the animation.

Hope this helps, Cheers!

Result example .gif (slowed down to .05s KeyTime)

[image]

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="ChrisW-shapeTransform">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="90"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Data).(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[1].(LineSegment.Point)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                    <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="35,25"/>
                </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="10"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Data).(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[2].(LineSegment.Point)" Storyboard.TargetName="path1">
                    <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="34.9687517366199,8.02473365979495E-07"/>
                </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="path1">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="10"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path1">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FFB60303"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FFB60303"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ChrisW-shapeTransform}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Path x:Name="path1" Fill="#FF23B603" Margin="0,0,0,25" Width="35" Height="25">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="3.40174928936676E-06,8.28996221002853E-07">
                            <LineSegment Point="3.40174928936676E-06,25.0000021090614"/>
                            <LineSegment Point="34.9999995333882,25.0000021090614"/>
                            <LineSegment Point="24.2397154485391,17.2785287275999"/>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
            <Path x:Name="path" Fill="#FF23B603" Height="25" Width="35" Margin="0,25,0,0">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="0,0">
                            <LineSegment Point="35.0000012644377,0"/>
                            <LineSegment Point="24.2397160835937,7.72147280089242"/>
                            <LineSegment Point="0,24.9999997857589"/>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```